# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT Android Json

Tags: android, gson, android-volley, retrofit, square

I am trying to implement Retrofit into my app to communicate with my server's end points. I have a Table in the backend called "Feature" that have id: number, name: text and roomID:number fields. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have followed Retrofit docs strictly. I get this error when I attempt to get a specific feature by ID from my database I get this error:

```
IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
06-13 17:21:20.896 15174-15180/xdesign.georgi.espc_retrofit W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.681ms
```

This is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            GitHubService gitHubService = GitHubService.retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);


            final Call<Feature> call = gitHubService.repoContributors(173);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Feature>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Feature> call, Response<Feature> response) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity","onResponce");
                    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    textView.setText(response.body().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Feature> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity","onFailure" + t.toString());
                    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    textView.setText("Something went wrong: " + t.getMessage());
                }


            });
        }
    });
}
```

GitHutService.java

```
interface GitHubService {
@GET("Features/{id}")
Call<Feature> repoContributors(@Path("id") int id);


public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
}
```

Feature.java

```
public class Feature {

String name;
int roomID;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getRoomID() {
    return roomID;
}

public void setRoomID(int roomID) {
    this.roomID = roomID;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Feature{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", roomID=" + roomID +
            '}';
}
}
```

> Note : This issue can happen in any networking library which parses
>   the JSON response and gives the final Java POJO back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your server responds with array of Feature objects but you have given  as your Pojo which is causing the issue.

Try using  as your generic class which will be used as a pojo for JSON, your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will to see if it  will resolve the issue:)

Comment: Welcome . I will edit the your question since this happens with any library which gives the response in POJO :)

Answer (score 0):

Your object class is not mapped as the json response, use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to get the response and paste the response [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to get the correct parameters in the object.